# How to INSERT or UPDATE a large number of rows (regarding the auto_increment value of a table)

Tags: mysql, insert, scrapy, sql-update, insert-update

I have a MySQL table with around 3 million rows (`listings`) at the moment. These listings are updated 24/7 (around 30 listings/sec) by a python script (`Scrapy`) using `pymsql` - so the performance of the queries is relevant!

If a `listing` doesn't exist (i.e. the `UNIQUE` `url`), a new record will be inserted (which is around every hundredth listing). The `id` is set to `auto_increment` and I am using a `INSERT INTO listings ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_seen_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. The update on `last_seen_at` is necessary to check if the item is still online, as I am crawling the search results page with multiple listings on it and not checking each individual URL each time.

```
+--------------+-------------------+-----+----------------+
| Field        | Type              | Key | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------------+-----+----------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned  | PRI | auto_increment |
| url          | varchar(255)      | UNI |                |
| ...          | ...               |     |                |
| last_seen_at | timestamp         |     |                |
| ...          | ...               |     |                |
+--------------+-------------------+-----+----------------+
```

## The problem:

At first, it all went fine. Then I noticed larger and larger gaps in the auto_incremented `id` column and found out it's due to the `INSERT INTO ...` statement: MySQL attempts to do the insert first. This is when the `id` gets auto incremented. Once incremented, it stays. Then the duplicate is detected and the update happens.

## Now my question is: Which is the best solution regarding performance for with long term perspective?

**Option A:** Set the `id` column to unsigned `INT` or `BIGINT` and just ignore the gaps. Problem here is I'm afraid of hitting the maximum after a couple of years updating. I'm already at an auto_increment value of around 12,000,000 for around 3,000,000 listings after two days of updating...

**Option B:** Switch to an `INSERT IGNORE ...` statement, check the affected rows and `UPDATE ...` if necessary.

**Option C:** `SELECT ...` the existing listings, check existence within python and `INSERT ...` or `UPDATE ...` dependingly.

**Any other wise options?**

---

**Additonal Info:** I need an `id` for information related to a `listing` stored in other tables (e.g. `listings_images`, `listings_prices` etc.). IMHO using the URL (which is unique) won't be the best option for foreign keys.

```
+------------+-------------------+
| Field      | Type              |
+------------+-------------------+
| listing_id | int(11) unsigned  |
| price      | int(9)            |
| created_at | timestamp         |
+------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: A fourth option may be to drop the auto_increment id column.

Comment: @P.Salmon yeah, thats what I suggested in my answer, that ID column is not needed, just make URL as PRIMARY KEY and add UNIQUE index on that

Comment: @P.Salmon I added the info, that there are more tables which store information about the listing and I therefor need an `id` - using a long string URL wouldn't be the best option in this case. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was in exact situation as yours

I have millions of records being entered by scraper into table, scraper was running every day

I tried following but failed

1. Load all urls into a Python `tuple` or `list` and while scraping, only scrape those which are not in the list - FAILED because at the time of loading urls into a Python `tuple` or `list` script consumed so much of server's RAM
2. Check each record before entering - FAILED because it made INSERTion process too slow because it first have to query the table with millions of rows and then decide whether to INSERT or not

**SOLUTION WORKED FOR ME:** (for table with millions of rows)

1. I removed `id` column because it is irreverent and I do not need that
2. Make `url` PRIMARY KEY since it will be unique
3. Add `UNIQUE` INDEX -- THIS IS MUST TO DO - It will increase your table's performance drastically
4. Do bulk inserts instead of inserting one-by-one (see pipeline code below)

Notice it is using `INSERT IGNORE INTO`, so only new records will be entered and if it exists, it will be ignored completely

If you use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT IGNORE INTO` in MySQL, the new records will be entered, but if a record exists, it will be updated

```
class BatchInsertPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.query = None

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        table = item['_table_name']
        del item['_table_name']

        if self.query is None:
            placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(item))
            columns = '`' + '`, `'.join(item.keys()).rstrip(' `') + '`'
            self.query = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO '+table+' ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )' \
                % (columns, placeholders)

        self.items.append(tuple(item.values()))

        if len(self.items) >= 500:
            self.insert_current_items(spider)   
        return item

    def insert_current_items(self,spider):
        spider.cursor.executemany(self.query, self.items)
        self.items = []


    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.insert_current_items(spider)
        self.items = []
```

Comment: Thank your for sharing this! This was my first idea, too - but I need an ID for relational tables, which store further information for the `listing` (like `listings_prices`, `listings_images` etc.). I will add this info to my original post.

Comment: Ok keep auto increment column as is, and then add a unique index on url column, then see if INSERT IGNORE works

Comment: Tried that before, but then the update is missing. The update is necessary to check if the ˋlistingˋ is still online. I am not crawling each individual URL, just the search results page with multiple listings on it.